# Android Read Document Html by Tag name

Tags: android, html, tags, jsoup, document

i'm trying to read a Document from Html using Jsoup. In fact, i've got the Document but now i'd like to read only a content by tag, i mean, i'd like to get the content text of the following example:

```
<span class="myLink"><a title="view text" href="/someref.html" onclick="somestuff"> My content text </a></span>
```

So i want to read only the text "My content text".

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String s = "<span class=\"myLink\"><a title=\"view text\" href=\"/someref.html\" onclick=\"somestuff\"> My content text </a></span>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(s);
    Elements el = doc.select("a");
    System.out.println(el.first().ownText());
```

output:

```
My content text
```